# How to list all repositories for a given topic with REST API in GitHub?

Tags: git, rest, github

I would like to update a README.md with a list of all repositories for a topic.
Before to write and update with a commit the change (automatically with a script)
**I would like to get all the string with repo URL for a given topic. I will save the date of each execution of the script.**

I've found a method to get all topics of a repository, not all the repository for a topic : https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#list-all-topics-for-a-repository in API V3

Moreover, it seems there is "related topic" or similar topic with synonymous or different typo.

Example :
https://github.com/search?q=abap&type=Topics

How could I get all the repo URL for a given topic (and its related topics) in order to update a readme.me file and (with a view to identify new repo) ?

Answer (score 3):

Here are two ways you can achieve this:

**1. CURL:**

```
curl -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.mercy-preview+json" 'https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=topic:XYZ'
```

Obviously, you can use `-u` to add your token or github username and password if your repo is private.

**2. Python:**

There is a library out there, PyGithub, that essentially has used most of the githhub developer API's and turned them to python functions.

[PyGithub](https://pygithub.readthedocs.io/en/latest/introduction.html)

Here is some code for you:

```
from github import Github

g = Github("YOUR_GITHUB_TOKEN")

TOPIC = 'php'
ORGANIZATION = 'your_github_org_name'

repos = g.search_repositories(query=f'topic:{TOPIC} org:{ORGANIZATION}')
for repo in repos:
    print(repo)
```

I wrote a pretty long function that did a lot of other checks as well, but this is the basic one that will get what you want (you can obviously trim the name of the repos returned and so on and so forth)

Hope this helps. Cheers.

Comment: The program doesn't work - no results are printed (additionally, the import needs to be `from github import Github`. The curl method is correct, but escaping as it causes an error to be returned - it works if single quotes are uesed, and the backslashes are removed.

Comment: what if i want to filter by more than one topic? I didn't find anything about it